# Auto populating MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, msgbox

I was wondering if anybody could help me turn the below into a msg box. Basically i want it to first check whether any of the below range's say **CHECK** and if they do a msgbox will appear explaining which rule has been breached. I have had an attempt at creating the variable but not really sure how to put this into practice in a msgbox.

```
Sub ErrorMsgBox()

Dim Error1 As String
    If Range("DaisyFreshRule").Value = "CHECK" Then
    Error1 = "Daisy Fresh Rule"
Else
End If

Dim Error2 As String
    If Range("MigrationRule").Value = "CHECK" Then
    Error2 = "Migration Rule"
Else
End If

Dim Error3 As String
    If Range("ServiceCreditRule").Value = "CHECK" Then
    Error3 = "Service Credit Rule"
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Sub ErrorMsgBox()

  Dim Error As String: Error=""

  If Range("DaisyFreshRule").Value = "CHECK" Then
    Error = vbNewLine & "Daisy Fresh Rule"
  End If

  If Range("MigrationRule").Value = "CHECK" Then
    Error = Error & vbNewLine & "Migration Rule"
  End If

  If Range("ServiceCreditRule").Value = "CHECK" Then
    Error = Error & vbNewLine & "Service Credit Rule"
  End If

  If Error <> "" Then
    MsgBox "The following checks have been detected:" & Error
  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ Ha! you beat me to it :D

Comment: I don't think '\n' will evaluate to a new line in vba

Comment: Yes it's been changed to vbLf. Thanks @Tom

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try

```
Sub ErrorMsgBox()
    Dim Err As String

    If UCase(Range("DaisyFreshRule").Value) = "CHECK" Then Err = Err & "Daisy Fresh Rule" & vbNewLine
    If UCase(Range("MigrationRule").Value) = "CHECK" Then Err = Err & "Migration Rule" & vbNewLine
    If UCase(Range("ServiceCreditRule").Value) = "CHECK" Then Err = Err & "Service Credit Rule" & vbNewLine

    If Not Err = vbNullString Then MsgBox prompt:=Err, Buttons:=vbCritical
End Sub
```

Comment: If there is no error, you will still get a msgbox :)

Comment: ++ nice :)  Time for me to almost hit the sack :D

Comment: Note, `Error` local variable is shadowing the `VBA.Conversion.Error` standard library function.

Comment: I too thought that so i built built it on my button so that only if any of the rules are broken then the msgbox then appears. Thanks for the help works great now

Comment: Just changed it so it doesn't overlap

Comment: Also @PeterMogford, Just clicked on your profile - your MD is my old boss - small world

Comment: very small @Tom